# Can I save my window layout in Netbeans 7.2?

Tags: layout, netbeans, windows-7, window, netbeans-7

As tabs tend to open inside wrong windows after some time, it would be helpful to store a preset layout in order to go back if things get messed up.

For example, if I am positioned in a *run tab* in the **Output pane** and open up a source file by double clicking in the project browser, the source file opens up in the tab in the **Output pane** instead of the main **Editor window**

[image: Screenshot in Netbeans 7.2 Win7 x64]

In menu `Window`, there is the option to `Reset Windows`, which fixes this bug. But then all my window customizations are lost.

So - I haven't figured out how to store my current window configuration. A rather nifty solution (e.g. backing up xml files) is acceptable.

Check this related bug on netbeans.org: [Source file opens in wrong window panel](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=209468)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this post](http://dirk.net/2008/10/11/change-the-netbeans-windows-layout/), the [Perspective plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=3273) lets you save a window layout (and switch between layouts). Unfortunately it's quite old (2008), so I'm not sure if it still works with the 7.2 version.

Comment: I installed the plugin, installation works fine in 7.2. I already tried out the save + open (=restore) function. Looks very promising.

Comment: It saves most of the layout configuration. However, floating windows return to be docked, and my small toolbar icons are back to large again. But it's the best answer so far.

Comment: Does this also work in NetBeans 8.0.1? Yes it does. 
Download the Perspective plugin for NetBeans 7:
http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=3273

https://blogs.oracle.com/NetBeansSupport/entry/how_to_download_and_install

Comment: I suddenly got big problem with the windows in NB 6.9.1 (I have an old Rails application). I have now saved the folder `6.9\config\Windows2Local` (when the windows was as I want them) from NB's working folder to a safe place. And every time the windows get bad I delete the `6.9\config\Windows2Local` and restore the saved copy.  It works the same for 8.0.2, but there I have no problems with the windows. It's an alternative if the plugin mentioned not works.

Comment: Works with 8.2 php edition too, after extracing .nbm from zip file.

Comment: Perspective plugin link is not available